# Unable to Build in Release mode in Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build, release

I am getting below error while try to build in release mode. However it build successfully in debug mode. I use TFS and Visual Studio 2015.

```
ERROR 1
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy "obj\Release\MyTestApp.exe" to 
            "D:\MyFile\Publish\app.publish\MyTestApp.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10.
            Failed. MyTestApp           

ERROR 2
Error       Unable to copy file "obj\Release\MyTestApp.exe" to
            "D:\MyFile\Publish\app.publish\MyTestApp.exe". Could not find a part of the
            path 'D:\MyFile\Publish\app.publish'. MyTestApp
```

Even if I change the path and try to publish it, it still shows the same error message with the paths.

Comment: are you able to build on Release mode locally? Would be good if you can share your code / project file

Comment: I am unable to build in release mode in local machine as well

Comment: It would seem like you have a compilation issue. check your build logs to see if MytestApp.exe was actually compiled correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have often faced this issue when I first compile my solution in debug mode and then in release mode (sometimes). 
I am currently using `Visual Studio 2019` but this should work for your version as well. You can try following options:

1. Use `Clean` & then `Rebuild-All` Option in Visual Studio
2. Close & Reopen Visual Studio
3. If the issue persists then most probably "dotnet.exe" is locking the
   files. Use `taskkill /im dotnet.exe` to kill it; issue should get
   resolved
4. Lastly, open Resource Monitor and check if there are any open handles that
   are locking your file. If yes, kill those handles.